# Adding draggable textarea inside HTML5's canvas

Tags: html, textarea, draggable, resizable

It is possible to add a draggable and resizable textarea inside a canvas tag?

I already tried this:

```
<canvas id="canvas2" width="650" height="850"> 
 <div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
    <textarea rows="2" cols="20">
      Example
    </textarea>
  </div>                    
</canvas>
```

But it doesn't show anything =S.

What else should I try?

Thanx.

Comment: if this is solved please post ans. that can other get benefit.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to make a paper kind of thing by including both *textarea* and *canvas*, and then toggling by altering the *z-index* in the `css` part of the elements.